# Select from two tables mysql in a particular order because the output must have a particular structure

Tags: mysql

I have a unique situation where I have to select particular columns from two tables in a particular order. Below is the table for the vendors

| vid | company | mno | phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Xoxoxo | MTN | 2459999999 |
| 2 | Vovovo | MTN | 2459998888 |
| 3 | Yrewmi | Vodafone | 2459997777 |

Here is the order_content table.

| oid | vendor_id | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 7 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 |

I want to select the vendor.company, vendor.mno, SUM(order_content.amount), vendor.phone for a particular ordercontent.oid selecting only vendors involved. I want to get the vendors details from the vendor table and sum up the amount for a particular order. Lets say order 2 that is `old = 2`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT vendor.company AS customerName, vendor.mno, SUM(orders_content.price) AS amount 
FROM orders_content, vendor 
WHERE orders_content.oid = 2 
GROUP BY orders_content.oid;
```

The result I am expecting

| customerName | mno | amount | phone | description | reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Vooxoo | MTN | 2 | 2459998888 | orders | 154013949 |
| Xoxoxo | MTN | 11 | 2459999999 | orders | 78793949 |

Comment: You haven't specified a relationship between the two tables, so you're getting a full cross product of the tables. You should use ANSI JOIN syntax, it's harder to forget this.

Comment: Since the order has multiple vendors, which one do you want in the result?

Comment: You cannot expect to get the SUM of the same order while wanting to get the different vendors at the same time! The best I see here you can get number of vendors besides the SUM of amount.

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: Maybe you want `GROUP BY orders_content.oid, vendor.vid` to get separate totals for each vendor?

Comment: Sorry guys, I have updated the question. I want the vendor details for all the vendors involved as well as the total amount each one sold from the order content table

Comment: @Barmar, that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a joining condition between the tables, and group by `vid`, not `oid`. You don't need to group by `oid` since the `WHERE` clause restricts to a single order.

```
SELECT vendor.company AS customerName, vendor.mno, SUM(orders_content.price) AS amount
FROM vendor
JOIN orders_content ON orders_content.vendor_id = vendor.vid
WHERE orders_content.oid = 2
GROUP BY vendor.vid
```